# How to translate a sentence in a logical language using prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a sentence and its syntax, where can I find the predicates prolog that allow me to write the sentence in a logical language?

Exists or any of you can help me to create a predicate that

takes as input the following string

```
(S (NP (NNP John))
    (VP (VBP see)
      (NP (NNP Mary))))
```

and return this

```
see(John,Mary)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want parse LISP structures to Prolog. Then [LisProlog](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/lisprolog/lisprolog.html), by Markus Triska, could be the appropriate tool. Using that and this snippet

```
test :- parse("(S (NP (NNP John))
        (VP (VBP see)
         (NP (NNP Mary))))",
          R),
    maplist(sexp_write(""), R).

sexp_write(Indent, E) :-
    is_list(E),
    format('~s~w~n', [Indent, E]),
    maplist(sexp_write([0' |Indent]), E).
sexp_write(Indent, E) :-
    format('~s~w~n', [Indent, E]).
```

I get

```
?- test.
[s(S),[s(NP),[s(NNP),s(John)]],[s(VP),[s(VBP),s(see)],[s(NP),[s(NNP),s(Mary)]]]]
 s(S)
 [s(NP),[s(NNP),s(John)]]
  s(NP)
  [s(NNP),s(John)]
   s(NNP)
   s(John)
 [s(VP),[s(VBP),s(see)],[s(NP),[s(NNP),s(Mary)]]]
  s(VP)
  [s(VBP),s(see)]
   s(VBP)
   s(see)
  [s(NP),[s(NNP),s(Mary)]]
   s(NP)
   [s(NNP),s(Mary)]
    s(NNP)
    s(Mary)
true .
```

Now you should decide about translating the *logical form* to Prolog term.

In generality, it's a difficult theme, because you need to do some choice about *quantification*. For your simple statement, you could begin with a very simple pattern matching, ignoring altogether the problem above.

```
sexp_to_term(S_exp, T_exp) :-
    parse(S_exp, [R]),
    termize(R, T),
    pattern(T, T_exp).

pattern(T, T_exp) :-
    T = 'S'('NP'('NNP'(Subj)),'VP'('VBP'(Verb),'NP'('NNP'(Obj)))),
    T_exp =.. [Verb, Subj, Obj].

termize(s(Tag), Tag).
termize([s(Tag)|Args], Term) :-
    maplist(termize, Args, ArgsT),
    Term =.. [Tag|ArgsT].
```

test:

```
?- gtrace,sexp_to_term("(S (NP (NNP John)) (VP (VBP see) (NP (NNP Mary))))", T).
T = see('John', 'Mary').
```

Comment: thanks, it would seem ideal, but I do not work,
I created a prolog file with the code lisprolog and clauses that you told me
but is the statement: ---
? - Gtrace, sexp_to_term ("(S (NP (NNP John)) (VP (VBP see) (NP (NNP Mary))))", T). ---
that ---
?-test. ---
give back
"no".

Comment: Use yap and without gtrace works, too bad it does not work for all syntactic forms but only subject verb complement, thank you anyway, would you be willing to give me private lessons obviously paid?

Comment: I could do (in italian :). mail me to see if we can reach an agreement (see my profile for e-mail). Ciao.

Comment: non riesco a trovare la tua email, scrivimi te per favore su ciardo.gabriele@gmail.com, grazie.

Answer (score 1):

I think @CapelliC's answer is better (+1), but I wanted to take a crack at it and see what I came up with. You can solve this without LisProlog, but you can be quite sure that LisProlog will do a *much* better job than my off-the-cuff DCG crap.

First for my convenience I wanted to stick your example sentence into the code so I don't have to keep retyping it:

```
sent("(S (NP (NNP John))
         (VP (VBP see)
             (NP (NNP Mary))))").
```

Now some helper DCG rules:

```
whitespace --> [X], { char_type(X, white) ; char_type(X, space) }, whitespace.
whitespace --> [].

char(C) --> [C], { char_type(C, graph), \+ memberchk(C, "()") }.
```

I need the `memberchk` in there to ensure that I don't put parenthesis into atoms.

```
chars([C|Rest]) --> char(C), chars(Rest).
chars([C]) --> char(C).

term(T) --> chars(C), { atom_chars(T, C) }.
term(L) --> list(L).

list(T) --> "(", terms(T), ")".

terms([]) --> [].
terms([T|Terms]) --> term(T), whitespace, !, terms(Terms).
```

There's mutual recursion between term and list, but this is what we want, because we want a list to be able to appear nested anywhere. Let's test the parsing:

```
?- sent(X), phrase(list(Y), X).
X = [40, 83, 32, 40, 78, 80, 32, 40, 78|...],
Y = ['S', ['NP', ['NNP', 'John']], ['VP', ['VBP', see], ['NP', ['NNP'|...]]]] ;
```

This looks good so far. The pattern matching looks very similar to @CapelliC's:

```
simplify(['S', ['NP', ['NNP', Subject]], 
               ['VP', ['VBP', Verb], 
                      ['NP', ['NNP', Object]]]], 
         Result) :-
    Result =.. [Verb, Subject, Object].
```

Unfortunately, using capitalized atoms is obscuring the intent here, which is actually quite natural. If we could use lowercase letters the pattern would look more like this:

```
simplify([s, [np, [nnp, Subject]], 
             [vp, [vbp, Verb], 
                  [np, [nnp, Object]]]], 
         Result) :-
    Result =.. [Verb, Subject, Object].
```

We're using the powerful "univ" operator here (`=..`) to generate a Prolog term from a list. You can think of this operator as the Lisp translator, because that's essentially what it does:

```
?- s(this, that) =.. X.
X = [s, this, that].

?- X =.. [s, this, that].
X = s(this, that).
```

So it should be clear how the pattern matching works. Let's see how the whole thing fits together:

```
?- sent(X), phrase(list(Y), X), simplify(Y, Z).
X = [40, 83, 32, 40, 78, 80, 32, 40, 78|...],
Y = ['S', ['NP', ['NNP', 'John']], ['VP', ['VBP', see], ['NP', ['NNP'|...]]]],
Z = see('John', 'Mary') .
```

For what it's worth, translating natural language sentences into logical propositions is a big question. It won't usually be this easy, but there are books that discuss how to approach the problem. I'd suggest checking out *Representation and Inference for Natural Language* for more information on this large problem.

So there you have it. The advantage to doing it by hand like this is that you can control what exactly from Lisp's grammar you want to take, and it's easy to extend or modify. The downside is that you will have to debug the grammar—and I'm quite sure there are problems with this one I didn't notice or take time to find (I am far from a DCG expert!). Absent better requirements I would definitely take @CapelliC's answer, but I thought it might be helpful to see how this could be approached from scratch.

Comment: Actually, output from your DCG it's more readable than LisProlog' output. Probably LisProlog formulae are cluttered by the need of futher evaluation.

Comment: This is obviously *far* from a real Lisp parser, so it may benefit from simplicity. But I prize correctness and I doubt my 15 minute DCG exercise is more correct than published code.

Comment: LisProlog is awesome, I think. The parser is also very compact. I've done some little programming in Autolisp (simple Autocad LISP) almost 25 years ago, but I don't have nostalgy of it.