# How to convert prolog parse tree back to a logical sentence

Tags: parsing, prolog, declarative, dcg

I managed to build the parse tree for given sentence and here it is, for the sentence: "The man went home."

```
T = s(np(det(the), n(man)), vp(v(went), np(n(home))))
```

1) How to use phrase/2 on this?

[How to translate a sentence in a logical language using prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953960/how-to-translate-a-sentence-in-a-logical-language-using-prolog/17759505#17759505) - is similar to what I need, but it's solution doesn't work on me.

2)I want to map this with grammar pattern and get the words tag.
`Det=the`, `N(Subject)=man`, `V=went`, `N(Object)=home`

Is there a way to map this tree with given set tree structures and identify the grammar. 
how can I use parse tree to identify Subject, verb, object, the grammar pattern and the generate the target language sentence.

---

Edited later..
I tried this code and it gives considerable answer. Any suggestions on this code.

```
sent("(s(np(n(man))) (vp(v(went)) (np(n(home)))))").

whitespace --> [X], { char_type(X, white) ; char_type(X, space) }, whitespace.
whitespace --> [].

char(C) --> [C], { char_type(C, graph), \+ memberchk(C, "()") }.

chars([C|Rest]) --> char(C), chars(Rest).
chars([C]) --> char(C).

term(T) --> chars(C), { atom_chars(T, C) }.
term(L) --> list(L).

list(T) --> "(", terms(T), ")".

terms([]) --> [].
terms([T|Terms]) --> term(T), whitespace, !, terms(Terms).

simplify([s,[np, [n,[Subject]]], [vp,[v,[Verb]],[np,[n,[Object]]]]],Result) :- Result = [Subject,Verb,Object].
```

Thanks Mathee

Comment: `phrase/2` relates a DCG rule and an input list of some kind. You can use it in either direction, but if you're neither parsing nor generating a list it probably isn't the right tool for the job. It worked for me in the other answer because Lisp s-expressions are inherently lists.

Comment: please check for code I added later. I followed your method. and it worked in SWI prolog. Can you please suggest improvements for the code to match with several grammer patters and identify the grammar pattern for given sentence.

Comment: `white` is tab and space; `space` includes those, so you only need `space` in `whitespace//0`. I would remove `Result` from `simplify/2` and just put the list as the second argument and have no body on this rule. Otherwise it looks good to me. Surprising, this wasn't what I thought you were asking at all, but it doesn't look bad to me. :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions. 
Do you think if I add more simplify rules with different patterns  it will work well in grammar matching with given sentence. Is this a good approach to identify source language grammar grammar pattern in language translation.

Comment: I thought originally you had a Prolog parse tree, not s-expressions. I would think handling a Prolog parse tree would be simpler than this. I don't think you'll run into trouble with `simplify/2` but you will want to aggressively refactor out common code and reuse as much as possible. I haven't done this kind of thing in depth nor do I know enough about your problem domain to speculate. Try it; if it works, great; if not, come back and try another approach. :)

Comment: Actually I don't know what is a parse tree and what is a s-expression. I think what I am getting is a s-expression. I use prolog with java. So for given sentence I get the T format from one prolog file and then give that parse tree output to the next prolog file which include above code. T is the out put from first prolog file.  can you please explain parse tree generation.

Comment: My email address is in my profile. Send me an email and I'll do my best to explain that way. This space is too cramped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simpler way to do is by means a visit of the tree, 'hardcoded' on the  symbols you are interested.

Here is a more generic utility, that uses ([=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2))/2 to capture a named part of the tree:

```
part_of(T, S, R) :- T =.. [F|As],
    (   F = S,
        R = T
    ;   member(N, As),
        part_of(N, S, R)
    ).

?- part_of(s(np(det(the), n(man)), vp(v(went), np(n(home)))),np,P).
P = np(det(the), n(man)) ;
P = np(n(home)) ;
false.
```

It's a kind of member/2, just for trees. BTW I don't understand the first part of your question: why do you want to use phrase/2 on a syntax tree ? Usually a grammar (the first argument to phrase/2) is meant to *build* a syntax tree from 'raw' characters stream...

Comment: glad to know things from your answer. But I need to compare the given tree with a grammar pattern, where I can get man as subject and home as object. 
For that I got the phrase idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953960/how-to-translate-a-sentence-in-a-logical-language-using-prolog/17759505#17759505.